# Symfony 1.4 what if I want a form field to be changed something through?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

Lets suppose I have a user registration form. Since the password must be stored md5 encoded, the best idea would be to convert it in redhand, but it looks `request` is read only. How to change a form field during processing?

Comment: What do you mean by *redhand*? By the way, md5 is weak. [Use something stronger](http://stackoverflow.com/a/401684/569101) (like sha1 or bcrypt).

Comment: after the request comes and before it goes to the database. In the meantime want I encode it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom Validator for the form. Create a class like this:

```
<?php

class encodeValidator extends sfValidatorBase
{
  /**
  * @see sfValidatorBase
  */
  protected function doClean($value)
  {
     return md5($value); //md5 can be replaced with another encoding method
  }
}
```

Next, when you create your form, add the custom validator you created, like this:

```
$this->setWidget('field_name', new sfWidgetFormInputText());
$this->validatorSchema['field_name'] = new encodeValidator();
```

Comment: isnt there are easier solution out there? A time ago, it was easier just edit the _POST array. And for example, there is an "auto increment" ID, I dont need it neither, but then validator would fail

Comment: Well, in frameworks you can always hack your way in order to implement things. This is just a "Symfony" way to achieve this. :P